# What happened to all the copper and other ores?

Tags: terraria

So I started a new world with the 1.2 update, and spent several hours mining minerals. From all my mining, not once did I come across any copper, which is supposed to be the most common mineral found in the game. What happened to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [patch notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nubZZSGBoUiuKFKzWT7raMrPI35MQtDWSsL-MbHFgqs/preview?pli=1&sle=true):

> - Your world has a chance to get alternative ore as a replacement for copper, iron, silver, and gold

There's no indication on what it's replaced *with* in the notes.

Gigazelle has found the following:

- copper = tin
- iron = lead
- silver = tungsten
- gold = platinum

Hardmode ores:

- cobalt = palladium
- mithril = orichalcum
- adamantite = titanium