# What are the tiers of the ores in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

As new player of Terraria, I'm lost with all the ores that are in game.

So, what are the tiers of the ores?

I don't know for example if gold is better than iron (for example in Minecraft iron is much better than gold)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to all the copper and other ores?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132882/what-happened-to-all-the-copper-and-other-ores)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of 1.2, every world gets either one or the other generated:

Standard Ores can be found almost everywhere underground:

- [Copper](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Copper_Ore) or [Tin](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tin_Ore)
- [Iron](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Iron_Ore) or [Lead](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lead_Ore)
- [Silver](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Silver_Ore) or [Tungsten](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tungsten_Ore)
- [Gold](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gold_Ore) or [Platinum](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Platinum_Ore)
- [Demonite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demonite_Ore) or [Crimtane](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimtane_Ore)

Demonite and Crimtane are rarely generated, so that's why [The Eater of Worlds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds) and the [The Brain of Ctulhu](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Brain_of_Cthulhu) drops them in large quantities.

Hardmode Ores are generated by destroying [Demon Altars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Altar) with a [Pwnhammer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pwnhammer). You can obtain this hammer by killing [the Wall of Flesh](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh), activating [Hardmode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode).

- [Cobalt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cobalt_Ore) or [Palladium](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Palladium_Ore)
- [Mythrill](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mythril_Ore) or [Orichalcum](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Orichalcum_Ore)
- [Adamantite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Adamantite_Ore) or [Titanium](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Titanium_Ore)

And these ores are always generated:

- [Meteorites](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Meteorite) fall after breaking a least one [Shadow Orb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb) or [Demon Heart](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Heart).
- [Hellstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone) is found almost anywhere in [The Underworld](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Underworld).
- [Chlorophyte](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Ore) is found in the [Underground Jungle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Jungle) after hardmode is activated.
- [Luminite](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Luminite) is dropped by the Moon Lord.

Additionally, [Hallowed Bars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_Bar) drop from certain hardmode bosses.

**Summary:**
Luminite > Chlorophyte > Hallowed > Titanium > Adamantite > Orichalcum > Mythrill > Palladium > Cobalt > Hellstone > Demonite/Crimtane > Meteorite > Platinum > Gold > Tungsten > Silver > Lead > Iron > Tin > Copper

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ores

Comment: You're placing way too much emphasis on OP's choice of words. He wants to know which metals are better than which, hallowed should be in that list.

Comment: since Hallowed Bars are mentioned even though don't have ores, why not mention Shroomite Bars also? so maybe update the answer?